# How to use std::for_each + std::execution::par without iterator?

Tags: c++

I would like to use `std::for_each(std::execution::par, ...)` with `tbb::parallel_for` style.

```
tbb::parallel_for(0, n, [](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r) { f(r); });
```

But, `std::for_each()` only accepts iterators.

```
std::vector<int32_t> v(0, n);
std::for_each(std::execution::par,
        v.begin(),
        v.end(),
        [&](int32_t& i) { f(i); });
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally reached to a solution.

```
class Iterator
    : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int64_t, int64_t>
{
public:
    Iterator() = default;
    Iterator(int64_t index) : index_(index) {}
    const int64_t& operator*() const { return index_; }
    const void operator++() { ++index_; }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& lhs) const { return index_ != lhs.index_; }
    const int64_t operator+(const Iterator& lhs) const { return index_ + lhs.index_; }
    int64_t operator-(const Iterator& lhs) const { return index_ - lhs.index_; }
private:
    int64_t index_;
};
std::for_each(std::execution::par,
              Iterator(0),
              Iterator(n),
              [&](int64_t idx) { f(idx); });
```

Comment: See also the proposed [iota range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view)

Comment: `std::iterator` is depcrecated since C++17. Better explicitly declare the types required via usings within your own iterator!

Answer (score 2):

Most standard algorithms operate on iterators, that is just the way they work, so they can be used with multiple containers.

However, `std::vector` uses random-access iterators, so you can apply indexes to the `begin` iterator, eg:

```
template<typename T, typename Callable>
void my_parallel_for(std::vector<T> &v, size_t startIdx, size_t endIdx, Callable c)
{
    std::for_each(std::execution::par,
        v.begin()+startIdx,
        v.begin()+endIdx,
        c);
}
```

```
std::vector<int32_t> v;
...
my_parallel_for(v, 0, n, [&](int32_t& i) { f(i); });
```

Comment: Some calculations do not use containers, or can't access to write back buffer(containers), so I need tbb-style parallel_for.

I realized that writing an iterator class would work, but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: @qqq ok, but that is not what you asked for in your question. You specifically asked for `std::for_each()`, which is an iterator-based algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tbb::counting_iterator` (https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/iterators/counting_iterator.html)

```
auto begin = tbb::counting_iterator<int>(0);
std::for_each(std::execution::par,
        begin,
        begin + n,
        [&](int32_t& i) { f(i); });
```

Boost also has it: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html

Comment: Thanks! 
Ah...I wanted to do it without using tbb.